# Why were the images from DART encode in a way that cropped the last one the way it did?

Tags: communication, dart

The last image from DART only includes about the top ⅒ of the image, but that portion of the image is in full quality. That suggests that the image encoding/compression is mostly a raster encoding. Off hand this seems to me like a rather odd choice. It prioritizes information that isn't very useful over data that would be more useful.

**Does anyone know (or have any informed speculation about) why the images were transmitted the way they were?**

---

The first alternative that comes to mind would have been some sort of global/progressive encoding  (e.g. something as simple ["progressive JPEG"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression)) that first sends low quality image data for the full field of view followed by progressively more detail. The potential advantage of that would be that, regardless of where the transmission is cut off, you get some information from the whole field of view at the expense of not getting really high quality.

The second alternative that comes to mind is even simpler: just re-order the pixels to transmit the center of the image first. The point of impact is likely the portion of the last image that is most interesting and the encoding used has only about a 50:50 chance of showing that.

Comment: The real answer to this is probably something like “that’s what the guy who programmed it decided”

Comment: @Topcode: if so, than (as with many bad decisions) it's not that they chose poorly, it's that they didn't even realize they were choosing at all.

Comment: As a person who actually designs digital cameras for spacecraft -- basically, that's how the data comes off the imager. Clearly, for this mission, they would not have wanted any significant latency in buffering or processing the data onboard the spacecraft -- they pretty much dumped the pixels to the transmitter as soon as they had them.

Comment: And most image compression techniques take advantage of the fact that pixels tend to be related to the ones near them.

Comment: The last image transmitted was corrupted due to LOS right before impact so the last image was not fully sent. I would assume the image was sent through the pixels, going left to right before top to bottom.

Comment: @fasterthanlight I just thought the image was interrupted by impact with the asteriod.

Comment: This was a low cost mission that used technology from the previous millennium. Technology from the previous millennium is pretty much standard in space missions. No data compression at all would be my guess.

Comment: @DaveTweed They'd certainly use *at least [delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding)* rather than all the bits of each pixel, no?

Comment: @uhoh: It's possible that there might have been some sort of line-by-line compression, but I agree with David Hammen -- probably not. The HDR images you get in space don't really benefit from it.

Comment: @uhoh What Dave & David said. You can compress such images using Fourier-based techniques like JPEG (which uses the Discrete Cosine Transform), but to get significant compression requires quantisation which discards high frequency components. Another option for multi-frame compression is to use the delta from the previous frame (combined with scaling & panning), but that requires a lot more CPU power & RAM, and is also a bit lossy (due to the quantisation involved in scaling). So it's generally better to send raw pixel data, and do post-processing on the ground.

Comment: @PM2Ring I disagree. Again, [delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) of a serial data stream for example offers significant *lossless* compression; doesn't loose any information and can be done on the fly. It's not something that you would use for pictures on your computer, this is used specifically in real-time data transmission where you don't have the whole image and compress it at once (like .png) but simply have a live, unpredictable stream of digital data. It would be almost silly NOT to use delta encoding unless you've got too much bandwidth and low frame rate.

Comment: @uhoh FWIW, I've implemented delta encoding (and RLE). Yes, it's fast, and can give substantial compression, but not with noisy data. The raw images on  https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-news/photos-show-drama-of-dart-asteroid-impact/ look rather noisy to me, so they wouldn't benefit much (if at all) from naive delta encoding. If you clean up that noise, then sure, delta encoding would be fine. But I'd rather have all the raw data. OTOH, I agree that the final frames of the impact would probably compress ok using delta.

Comment: Regarding latency, I'd be surprised if the amount of time to compress an image (even using lossless compression) is anywhere near the time needed to transmit it. Latency (for any significant percentage of the image) would probably be reduced by compression. - Or is someone asserting that the bandwidth off the sensor is comparable to the bandwidth back to earth? That would be extremely surprising to me.

Comment: @uhoh " Again, delta encoding of a serial data stream for example offers significant lossless compression"  No, it doesn't. It can help save space if you can reduce the dynamic range (which you can't because of very harsh shadows). Or if you do some additional compression afterwards. A pure delta between pixels doesn't help at all in images like these. A delta between images doesn't help either, the frames are too different from each other.

Comment: @asdfex I don't understand why you think that is so, can you elaborate on why exactly delta encoding of "images like these" would not offer significant lossless compression? Are we talking about what the definition of "significant" is perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

> The first alternative that comes to mind would have been some sort of global/progressive encoding

Yes, and that's what you are looking at. The last frame is a sub-resolution image, and additionally contains only low frequency components.

It's just that even the progressive pass was cut off very early. That ~10% of a frame we see is less than 1% of the data from the CMOS sensor, which is leaps better than a simple scan line raster strategy would achieve.

Comment: Is that a fact or speculation? Please provide some sources.  Do we have access to raw data? The published images seem to be heavily post-processed.

Comment: https://dart.jhuapl.edu/Gallery/

Comment: Where exactly can I find your information on that page? The caption of the image in question definitely doesn't help anything.

Comment: agreed with asdfex.  I can believe that the final DRACO image doesn't have the detail of the others, but I wouldn't call it obvious.